# Sitecore 7:BrightCove with Solr -Index mediaframework_brightcove_index was not found

Tags: indexing, sitecore, synchronization, brightcove, sitecore7

On Clicking Import on bright cove Media framework in Sitecore 7,nothing gets imported and instead i see the below issue in sitecore logs.Any idea on how to solve this?

ManagedPoolThread #8 09:17:35 ERROR MediaFramework *** Sync failed. 
Exception: System.ArgumentException 
Message: Index mediaframework_brightcove_index was not found 
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch 
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name) 
at Sitecore.Integration.Common.Utils.ContentSearchUtil.FindOne[T](String indexName, Expression`1 filter) 
at Sitecore.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Synchronize.VideoSynchronizer.GetSearchResult(Object entity, Item accountItem) 
at Sitecore.MediaFramework.Synchronize.SynchronizerBase.SyncItem(Object entity, Item accountItem) 
at Sitecore.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Synchronize.VideoSynchronizer.SyncItem(Object entity, Item accountItem) 
at Sitecore.MediaFramework.Pipelines.MediaSyncImport.MediaSyncItemImport.SyncItem.Process(MediaSyncItemImportArgs args)

ManagedPoolThread #4 09:17:35 INFO Job ended: Import MediaFramework Content (units processed: )

Please let me know if I am missing any setting.

IMPORTANT:We are using Solr and not the lucene search so accordingly modified "Sitecore.ContentSearch.MediaFramework.Brightcove.config" to include solr search configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't leave your configuration from brightcove file for Solr.
But I guess, at least, it should be something like this:

```
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <contentSearch>
            <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
                    <!-- mediaframework_brightcove_index -->
                    <index id="mediaframework_brightcove_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                        <param desc="core">itembuckets</param>
                        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
                        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
                            <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/sync" />
                        </strategies>
                        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
                            <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                                <Database>master</Database>
                                <Root>{7150B2B1-EB68-40EE-991F-2AFEDB532C46}</Root>
                            </crawler>
                        </locations>
                        <!-- configuration -->
                    </index>
                </indexes>
            </configuration>
        </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>
</configuratin>
```